# mouseover not working due to over div

Tags: jquery, mouseenter

In [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yK85J/) fiddle , I have on the visibility of the user-halo div , due to this my avatar image mouseover is not working please advise how i can start the mouseover of avatar image .
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you update the hover div to bind to `$("#user-halo-1")` rather than `$("#user-avatar-image-1")` it starts reacting again. Is that what you want? Otherwise you'll need to play around with the z-indexes or explain more about what you want and how you want it to look.

http://jsfiddle.net/yK85J/2/

Comment: it mouseover is called only when i take the mouse from right , and it is not called when i take the mouse from left.